# Where can I find customs/import fees for Israel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, israel, fees-and-charges

Where can I find the fees applicable for entering Israel (and declaring) more than the exempt amount of personal products (foodstuffs). I've found in multiple locations that I can bring up to $200 worth of items for personal use and (including?) 3kg of foodstuffs. 
But what if I want to go over that amount and pay the fees?
I would be entering on a student visa.

Comment: I want to have for my own personal use, but don't really want to just "smuggle" it in through the green line if it's not allowed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of all the customs and import fees is available on the [Israeli tax authority](http://ozar.mof.gov.il/ita2013/eng/mainpage.htm) along with explanations, forms etc.

And [this](https://taxes.gov.il/customs/PersonalImport/Pages/CustomsGuideTayar.aspx) is their guide for customs for tourists, including student visas (In Hebrew). The guide specifies exactly what is exempt from fees, food is exempt for up to a total of 3 kg, as long as each kind of food doesn't exceed 1 kg.

The list of fees is available [here](http://62.219.95.10/misimmerukht/) (In Hebrew).

Specifically for your question, the fees on "mixed food up to 15 kg" (מזון מעורב עד 15 ק"ג) are:

- 17% for goods worth 75$-500$
- 17% + 2.93 ILS for each kg for goods worth 500$-1000$
- "according to the imported item" for goods worth more than 1000$.

<sup>* - 17% is the VAT is Israel.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Israel uses a "Red Line Green Line" system, where if you have something to declare you go through the red line at the airport and they figure out duty and you pay. In the unlikely event you are using a land border, I suppose the border guard and customs is somewhere nearby.

Note that import of non-Kosher meat is [prohibited](http://www.thejc.com/lifestyle/food/how-holy-land-got-a-pork-habit), on top of whatever rules apply to food.

I have a hard time imagining what you would bring that is not readily available inside Israel.

Comment: But is there no way to estimate duty ahead of time?

Comment: Google says http://www.dutycalculator.com/country-guides/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-Israel/